# How to hide javascript animation outside of certain borders?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wrapper

I'm new to the wold of javascript/jquery, but had this fantastic idea for an effect for my webpage. Let me explain the layout abit.

My website is contained within a wrapper div, which assures that my content remains at 1000px and centered on the screen regardless of the width of monitor (assuming the monitor is bigger than 1000px). This content contains a header image that is presently used to display a colourful image (1000x400px) displaying the title of the website/company/etc. So this image is the width of the content container.

I thought it would be cool to instead of having the name of the company set on the image, have it scroll left to right, right to left on the image. This can be done with jquery and the animate() function (or a function close to it). The problem is that once the website title has scrolled to one extreme of the webpage, it will overflow out of the 1000x400px image and outside of the content container - thus into the wrapper region, which is simply a grey background.

My problem is that I can't conceptualize a way to hide the scrolling text (which would be represented by a very high z-index) behind the background wrapper (which is a simple background, so the lowest index possible). I only want the section of the scrolling text that is over the 1000px-wide content container to be visible. Anyone would know how to hide what is over the wrapper background? I thought of maybe recreating the wrapper background with some divs delimited by the presence of the content container; this div would have the highest z-index possible so it would hide anything that it superimposes. Is there a better/easier way to implement this?

Let me know if I'm not making sense :)

Pat

Comment: This is not an answer... although I was tempted to post it as one.  I would stay away from scrolling text.  People despise it... almost as much as blinking text.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Not as much as scrolling blinking text.

Comment: You could check out the HTML marquee element, it requires no JavaScript and should give the correct effect you are looking for. I also agree with Jason, not a lot of people like scrolling text.

Comment: Without seeing the page you are mention I am not 100% sure of what you are asking, I believe that it would be doable using css, overflow: hidden; Also as a side question how many images are you having on this page? Having too many images will increase load time and drive users away from your site.

Comment: Thanks. First off, the scrolling text would have a low opacity, so it's much less of the type of text effect that people despise (it's more aimed at making my 1000x400px image 'eye-candy'). As it is right now, I have the name of my website in large very size (and at maybe 0.3 opacity) on the image. I want to keep the same visibility, just make it scroll very slow across the image. Load time is something I haven't thought of yet, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but;

If the scrolling text is a **child** of the **wrapper div**, then all that needs to be done is to apply the style **overflow:hidden;** to the **wrapper div**.

Comment: That's something I haven't thought of yet, and I think it'll work. I'll try it once I get to work, I'll let you know how it goes :)

Comment: overflow:hidden did it. I should have caught that myself, but thanks for the nudge in the right direction.